# Yii2 - Unable to find 'app\models\User' in file: backend/models/User.php. Namespace missing?

Tags: yii2

I used both namespace in this file backend/models/User.php

When I use namespace app\models; It shows Unable to find 'backend\models\User'.

If I use namespace backend\models; It shows Unable to find 'app\models\User'

```
<?php
//namespace app\models;
namespace backend\models;

use Yii;
use yii\base\NotSupportedException;
use yii\behaviors\TimestampBehavior;
use yii\db\ActiveRecord;
use yii\web\IdentityInterface;


class User extends ActiveRecord implements IdentityInterface
{
    const STATUS_DELETED = 0;
    const STATUS_ACTIVE = 10;
    const ROLE_USER = 10;

    /**
     * @inheritdoc
     */
    public static function tableName()
    {
        return 'admin';
    }

    /**
     * @inheritdoc
     */
    public function behaviors()
    {
        return [
            TimestampBehavior::className(),
        ];
    }

    /**
     * @inheritdoc
     */
    public function rules()
    {
        return [
            ['status', 'default', 'value' => self::STATUS_ACTIVE],
            ['status', 'in', 'range' => [self::STATUS_ACTIVE, self::STATUS_DELETED]],

            ['role', 'default', 'value' => self::ROLE_USER],
            ['role', 'in', 'range' => [self::ROLE_USER]],
        ];
    }

    /**
     * @inheritdoc
     */
    public static function findIdentity($id)
    {
        return static::findOne(['id' => $id, 'status' => self::STATUS_ACTIVE]);
    }

    /**
     * @inheritdoc
     */
    public static function findIdentityByAccessToken($token, $type = null)
    {
        throw new NotSupportedException('"findIdentityByAccessToken" is not implemented.');
    }

    /**
     * Finds user by username
     *
     * @param string $username
     * @return static|null
     */
    public static function findByUsername($username)
    {
        return static::findOne(['username' => $username, 'status' => self::STATUS_ACTIVE]);
    }

    /**
     * Finds user by password reset token
     *
     * @param string $token password reset token
     * @return static|null
     */
    public static function findByPasswordResetToken($token)
    {
        if (!static::isPasswordResetTokenValid($token)) {
            return null;
        }

        return static::findOne([
            'password_reset_token' => $token,
            'status' => self::STATUS_ACTIVE,
        ]);
    }

    /**
     * Finds out if password reset token is valid
     *
     * @param string $token password reset token
     * @return boolean
     */
    public static function isPasswordResetTokenValid($token)
    {
        if (empty($token)) {
            return false;
        }
        $expire = Yii::$app->params['user.passwordResetTokenExpire'];
        $parts = explode('_', $token);
        $timestamp = (int) end($parts);
        return $timestamp + $expire >= time();
    }

    /**
     * @inheritdoc
     */
    public function getId()
    {
        return $this->getPrimaryKey();
    }

    /**
     * @inheritdoc
     */
    public function getAuthKey()
    {
        return $this->auth_key;
    }

    /**
     * @inheritdoc
     */
    public function validateAuthKey($authKey)
    {
        return $this->getAuthKey() === $authKey;
    }

    /**
     * Validates password
     *
     * @param string $password password to validate
     * @return boolean if password provided is valid for current user
     */
    public function validatePassword($password)
    {
        return Yii::$app->security->validatePassword($password, $this->password_hash);
    }

    /**
     * Generates password hash from password and sets it to the model
     *
     * @param string $password
     */
    public function setPassword($password)
    {
        $this->password_hash = Yii::$app->security->generatePasswordHash($password);
    }

    /**
     * Generates "remember me" authentication key
     */
    public function generateAuthKey()
    {
        $this->auth_key = Yii::$app->security->generateRandomString();
    }

    /**
     * Generates new password reset token
     */
    public function generatePasswordResetToken()
    {
        $this->password_reset_token = Yii::$app->security->generateRandomString() . '_' . time();
    }

    /**
     * Removes password reset token
     */
    public function removePasswordResetToken()
    {
        $this->password_reset_token = null;
    }
}
```

Comment: does your user model has this-   namespace backend\models;

Comment: yes.. shows this error Unable to find 'app\models\User' in file: /home/kometonl/public_html/demo/backend/models/User.php. Namespace missing?

Comment: can u post your user model code. not the whole one only the relevant part

Comment: <?php
//namespace app\models;
namespace backend\models;

use Yii;
use yii\base\NotSupportedException;
use yii\behaviors\TimestampBehavior;
use yii\db\ActiveRecord;
use yii\web\IdentityInterface; ...

Comment: @Kartz Post User model code in the question.

Comment: you r trying to do a user-login is it?       if yes in backend/config/main.php make sure      'identityClass' => 'backend\models\User',

Comment: @Kartz update me if u still have error

Answer (score 0):

I think your problem is, that you have two different models and try to use them both in one namespace, but this won't work.
You can alias one namespace, so you can use both different models.
eg.:

```
<?php
namespace app\models; 
// there exist a model "User"
// and you wanna use also the User model under common\models\
use common\models\User as CUser;
```

Another solution is to prefixing the namespace to the model like

```
<?php
namespace app\models;
$cuser = new \common\models\User();
```

see [PHP Namespaces explained](http://daylerees.com/php-namespaces-explained/http://)